# PayPal Chained payment using dynamic variables

Tags: php, arrays, paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

I've got the PayPal chained payment working so that it works by inputting the receivers email addresses and the amount in quote marks in the code, but I cannot get this working dynamically using variables that have stored data from the query string.

I am using:
    https://github.com/braintreedev/paypal-adaptive-payments-wrapper-php
as the framework behind the code below:

```
$price = $_GET['price'];
$projectid =$_GET['projid'];
$developeremail = $_GET['devemail'];

$devprice = $price * 0.9;

$paypal = new PayPal($config);

$result = $paypal->call(
  array(
'actionType'  => 'PAY',
'currencyCode'  => 'GBP',
'feesPayer'  => 'EACHRECEIVER',
'memo'  => 'Payment for project',

'cancelUrl' => 'cancel.php',
'returnUrl' => 'success.php',

'receiverList' => array(
  'receiver' => array(
      array(
      'amount'  => '100',
      'email'  => 'pay@websource.com',
      'primary' => 'true',
      ),

      array(
      'amount' => '90',
      'email'  => 'developer@websource.com',
    ),
  ),
),
  ),

  'Pay'
);
```

The code above is working but I want to swap the "developer@websource.com" email to the $developeremail variable and the amount to $devprice and the amount for "pay@websource.com" to be the value of $price but it doesn't process.

After doing some research it is because it is an associative array and the PHP engine cannot read variables, Do you guys know of any ways around this? I can't be the first person with this problem, right?

Comment: what error does it give you when you directly add in your variables. e.g
changing 'amount' => '100' to 'amount' => $price?

Comment: No error as there is no error handling at the moment just:if ($result['responseEnvelope']['ack'] == 'Success') {
  $_SESSION['payKey'] = $result["payKey"];
  $paypal->redirect($result);
} else {
  echo 'Handle the payment creation failure';
}

Comment: From what I can see there is nothing wrong with your code. Check your applications error logs / Apache error logs.

Comment: Sorry to cause confusion @Enoch, I am looking at converting the quotes used in 'amount' and 'email' to dynamic variables, the code shown works as it still uses those quotes

Answer (score 0):

What happens when you do this?

```
$price = $_GET['price'];
$projectid =$_GET['projid'];
$developeremail = $_GET['devemail'];

$devprice = $price * 0.9;

$paypal = new PayPal($config);

$result = $paypal->call(
  array(
'actionType'  => 'PAY',
'currencyCode'  => 'GBP',
'feesPayer'  => 'EACHRECEIVER',
'memo'  => 'Payment for project',

'cancelUrl' => 'cancel.php',
'returnUrl' => 'success.php',

'receiverList' => array(
  'receiver' => array(
      array(
      'amount'  => $price,
      'email'  => 'pay@websource.com',
      'primary' => 'true',
      ),

      array(
      'amount' => $devprice,
      'email'  => $developeremail,
    ),
  ),
),
  ),

  'Pay'
);
```

Comment: It comes back saying the result isnt a success :(

Comment: do a var_dump of $results and let's see the data being sent to the api

Answer (score 0):

To find out what the problem is var_dump the $result, in my case the problem was that for a chained payment you need more than one secondary receiver, so i switched to parallel payment instead, thanks for all your help guys